# Docker engine startup with parameters on OS X Sierra

Tags: docker, docker-engine

I have a OS X Sierra.
I have a Docker at below OS...

I wanna to change startup parameters of Docker Engine (Daemon) on boot my Mac.
For example, i want to specify -H tcp://127.0.0.1 parameter for startup.

Comment: i tried set a DOCKER_OPTS="-H tcp://......", edit a com.docker.vmnet.plist (or something like that), but it file was unawailable for edit ):

Comment: solved by adding: unix:///Users/[user]/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/s60 for connect

Answer (score 0):

As can be seen when you inspect

```
#~ screen ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/com.docker.driver.amd64-linux/tty

/ # grep docker.sock /etc/init.d/docker
    DOCKER_OPTS="${DOCKER_OPTS} -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
```

this is currently not possible (unless you want to change the ramdisk image). Docker doesn't allow settings to be set from configuration file and as a flag at the same time. Which would be the case if you would add "hosts": into daemon.json.

Answer (score 0):

solved by adding: unix:///Users/[user]/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Da‌​ta/s60 for connect